# Don't resize the height in a background image

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying my hands on responsive design in CSS but is stuck on one problem.

I have a background image in my CSS that is resizing when I'm changing the browser size. The problem is that I only want it to resize in width and not height. Is this possible?

So what I would like to achieve is that when I resize the window the height of the background picture should be static but the width would be resized.
The classic "stretch-to-fit" would be perfect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you only need to write to find the solution. =)

The css function background-clip: content-box; solved my problem.

Comment: You may also want to check out background size.  http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```